# Why is vcvarsall.bat needed for Python package installs on Windows, even when precompiled .pyd is available?

Tags: python, regex, windows, python-3.x, package

I'd like to install Python package ***regex*** and I got error `"unable to find vcvarsall.bat"`. I know there is a bunch of vcvarsall.bat related questions. The point is that the error is because the program tries to find a compiler and compile some C extensions, but in the case of regex package, the precompiled .pyd file is already included, so why does it try to compile? Can I somehow tell pip to use the .pyd file provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` installs from source, always. It cannot use the `.pyd` file included because it doesn't know how to install such files.

Instead of installing with `pip`, install manually, or better yet, get an installer from  [Christoph Golhke's Windows builds](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#regex) instead. These come in 32bit and 64bit variations, while the `pyd` file in the `regex` distribution is for Window 32bit only.

Comment: Does those installers work in a way, that the package is then listed in pip and can be uninstalled?

Comment: @user87690: I don't know. I suspect not, but that the packages are listed in the Windows installed programs list instead, and you can uninstall from there.

Comment: So I would need to manage two lists instead of one. Why can't just pip install the binary when it just mean placing one file to appropriate location? Why it can't be instrued by information in setup.py? (Sorry for my whining :-) )

Comment: @user87690: because `setup.py` was never designed for that use case. For that you either install eggs, or more recently, wheel files. But the `regex` project has not produced such files, it has instead chosen a non-standard and frankly, rather limited method of including a pre-compiled `.pyd` file in the source tarball. That is, unfortunately, the wrong method.

Comment: So I added a comment on https://code.google.com/p/mrab-regex-hg/issues/detail?id=84 .